# How do you use Javascript to insert bulk data into mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql

When I attempt to insert bulk data into mysql with javascript I get the following error:

```
ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1


var users = [
{"name" : "Person1", "id" : 1, "photo" : "/images/1.jpg"},
{"name" : "Person2", "id" : 2, "photo" : "/images/2.jpg"},
{"name" : "Person3", "id" : 3, "photo" : "/images/3.jpg"},
]

var insert_users = (users) =>
    sql.autoconnect().query(
    "INSERT INTO users (name, id, photo) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", users,
    function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      sql.autoconnect().end();
    }
  );
```

Comment: You can only insert one at a time with that particular query.

Comment: @tadman so what kind of query should I use to insert more than one at a time? Or how do I make it so that I don't open to many connections at once inserting one at a time if I do it that way. I tried that but it was kicking me out with to many connections. My real query is taking in more data.

Comment: It really depends on the driver. Is this using the `node-mysql` driver?  Try a nested array  `var users = [["p1",1,"1.jpg"],["p2",2,"2.jpg"],["p3",3,"3.jpg"]];` and use a single place holder in the SQL text `"INSERT INTO users (n,i,p) VALUES ?", users, function(err) {...});`

Comment: I tried your suggestion also but got the response: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '''Person1'', 1, '/images/1.jpg''' at line 1. Any other suggestions?